# Retrieve my own profile information stored in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying retrieve Name and email address that are stored for my account in my phone. I tried the following:

```
    Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int count = c.getCount();
    String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
    boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
    int position = c.getPosition();
    if (count == 1 && position == 0) 
    {
        String columnValue = null;
        for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) 
        {
            String columnName = columnNames[j];
            columnValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnName));
            Log.e("Name:", "Value" + columnValue);
        }

    }
    c.close();
```

And permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

The above logs lot of raw data including my name but I am not able to retrieve specifically my name from it?

Other thing How do I get my email address too?

Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_RAW_CONTACTS_URI` instead of `ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI` if you want to get email address or other entries.

Comment: I get the same result..There are lot of junk details in the array. How do I pick specific name from it?

Comment: I was confused about it before, and pulled the contact db file to investigate what happened inside. You can have a try.

Comment: Contact DB in the sense?